# Mysql "SOURCE <file>" importing of UTF8 dump gives question marks

Tags: mysql, sql, utf-8, import

I have searched online for a solution and none of the solutions that I found online seems to work here.

My problem is that I have a MySQL dump (SQL file) containing hebrew text values that is saved in UTF8 encoding, and when I import it using "`source [file]`" it saves the hebrew characters as question marks (???).

Now, when I look at the SQL file (cat [file]) I can see the hebrew characters properly.

Even when I try to copy & paste the SQL commands from the output that "`cat`" gave directly into the MySQL command line, it works as well.

It only fails when I use "`SOURCE [file]`" (which I need, because it is a HUGE file).

I have also tried the following:

1. `mysql -uroot -p[pass] --default-character-set=utf8` , and then "SET NAMES utf8" and then "SOURCE [file]" - Gives question marks.
2. Login to mysql client, then do "`SET NAMES utf8`", "`SET COLLATE utf8_bin`" (this is the settings for all the tables in the DB) - Gives question marks.
3. `CREATE DATABASE [db_name] DEFAULT CHARACTER SET UTF8` with the previous setting (section 2 above) - Gives question marks.
4. `mysql -uroot -p[pass] --default-character-set=utf8 [db_name] < [file.sql]` - Gives question marks.
5. `set character_set_filesystem utf8` and then running `source [file]` - Gives question marks.

None of these works properly, the ONLY thing that works is if I do copy+paste directly from cat's output to mysql command line, which is not an option because of the length of the file (several hundreds of MB).

Please help, thanks!

Comment: How did you set the collate of your database when you created it?

Comment: ALTER TABLE [dbname] COLLATE 'utf8_bin'.   I've tried this too, didnt help either.  I don't actually think its realy a DB issue, but more of how the data is transfered when using "SOURCE".  Because a direct copy&paste works.

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character\_set\_%';` Maybe you should head through this https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CONFKB/Characters+Appear+as+Question+Marks+Using+MySQL

Answer (score 2):

Will be problem reading the file as `< file.sql`.

As documented about using [**MySQL in batch mode**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/batch-mode.html)
If you are running mysql under Windows and have some special characters in the file `< file.sql` might cause problems, use this instead:

> mysql -e "source file.sql" dbname ... --default-character-set=UTF8

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I managed to solve this problem by creating a PHP "import" script.

First, I took the entire SQL file and split it into two files: structure (commands that create the tables and structure) and data.

Then, I just ran the entire structure.sql file using mysql_query, and took the data file, explode it by "\n" to get the seperate lines of all the INSERTs, and then ran them using a loop and mysql_query.

I didnt even need to include "SET NAMES utf8", figures out once I removed this line everything worked perfectly.

I know this isn't an ideal solution, but it is one that worked for me.